# Sql query to get table data output in HTML format in sql server?

Tags: sql, html, save, text-editor

Sql query to get table data output in HTML format in sql server?

Comment: What exactly is the issue you are having?

Comment: How html source code in SQL 2012 to write?

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, What have you already tried? What is your data structure? What is your expected output? Are you wanting a single `VARCHAR` returning the data in a `HTML` format? Do you already know how to connect to your database (given you've highlighted this as a html5 question)?